# Group by Column A, and Remove Duplicates from Another Column in SQL

Tags: sql, impala

I am trying to group column 1 by their values, and remove duplicate values of column 2 within the group.

For example,

Input

[image]

Output

[image]

I assume I need to use the function *group by* column 1 and use *distinct* to column 2, but I am not sure how to implement it.

Comment: Simply `SELECT DISTINCT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT Column_1,Column_2
from your_table
```

or

```
SELECT Column_1,Column_2
FROM YOUR_TABLE
GROUP BY Column_1,Column_2
```

Comment: You can also do UNION, and INTERSECT.

Answer (score 0):

You can do
SELECT distinct col2,
col1
from (Table)
GROUP BY 2

Comment: This will not produce the desired outcome.

Comment: This is not a working SQL.
1. GROUP BY needs a columnname.
2. all other columns must be in a aggregate function (sum,...)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).